Spring boot JPA query optimization
I'm trying to optimize a Spring Boot and JPA based blog application.
I'm struggling with the performance of a query that retrieves all posts from a board and its sub-boards.
At first, it took 44 seconds to fetch pagination data out of 5 millions data. After implementing DTO projection and index, it improved a little bit but it still takes 18 seconds for 10m data.
Are there any advanced optimization techniques I should consider or any things I miss?
I heard using Slice would be faster but for this, I would like to use Page and I could use a cache mechanism but I would like to reduce the time first.
Here are the related codes
Member entity
public class Member extends BaseEntity
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String nickname;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "score")
    private int score;

    private String role;

    private String url;

    private String role;

    private boolean isRemoved;
}


Board entity
public class Board extends BaseEntity
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean isAdminOnly;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer orderIndex;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Board parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Board> children = new ArrayList<>();
}


Post entity
@Table(
        name = "post",
        indexes = {
                @Index(name = "idx_post_id", columnList = "board_id, member_id, id"),
        }
)
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
public class Post extends BaseEntity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqPost")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seqPost", sequenceName = "seq", initialValue = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")
    private String content;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int voteCount;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "member_id", nullable = false)
    private Member member;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "board_id", nullable = false)
    private Board board;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
    List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
}


Repository
@Query("SELECT new com.payload.response.post.PostMultiResponse(" +
            "m.id, " +
            "m.nickname, " +
            "b.id, " +
            "b.name, " +
            "p.id, " +
            "p.title, " +
            "p.content, " +
            "p.voteCount, " +
            "SIZE(p.comments) , " +
            "p.createdAt) " +
            "FROM Post p " +
            "JOIN Member m ON m.id = p.member.id " +
            "JOIN Board b ON b.id = p.board.id " +
            "WHERE p.board.id IN :boardIds " +
            "AND (:keyword IS NULL OR LOWER(p.title) LIKE CONCAT('%', :keyword, '%')) " +
            "ORDER BY p.id DESC")
    Page<PostMultiResponse> findAllPostByBoardId(@Param("boardIds") List<Long> boardIds, 
                                                 @Param("keyword") String keyword, 
                                                 Pageable pageable);

This is the query performed by JPA
    select
        m1_0.id,
        m1_0.nickname,
        b1_0.id,
        b1_0.name,
        p1_0.id,
        p1_0.title,
        p1_0.content,
        p1_0.vote_count,
        (select
            count(1) 
        from
            comment c1_0 
        where
            p1_0.id=c1_0.post_id),
        p1_0.created_at 
    from
        post p1_0 
    join
        member m1_0 
            on m1_0.id=p1_0.member_id 
    join
        board b1_0 
            on b1_0.id=p1_0.board_id 
    where
        p1_0.board_id=? 
        and (
            ? is null 
            or lower(p1_0.title) like concat('%',?,'%') escape ''
        ) 
    order by
        p1_0.id desc limit ?,
        ?
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(p1_0.id) 
    from
        post p1_0 
    join
        member m1_0 
            on m1_0.id=p1_0.member_id 
    join
        board b1_0 
            on b1_0.id=p1_0.board_id 
    where
        p1_0.board_id=? 
        and (
            ? is null 
            or lower(p1_0.title) like concat('%',?,'%') escape ''
        )

-----------------------------------+
| -> Limit/Offset: 10/1000 row(s)  (cost=1.65 rows=0) (actual time=0.0133..0.0133 rows=0 loops=1)
    -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=1.65 rows=1) (actual time=0.0127..0.0127 rows=0 loops=1)
        -> Sort row IDs: p.id DESC  (cost=1.05 rows=1) (actual time=0.0121..0.0121 rows=0 loops=1)
            -> Filter: ((p.board_id = 1) and (match p.title,p.content against ('ti' in boolean mode)) and (p.member_id is not null))  (cost=1.05 rows=1) (actual time=0.0052..0.0052 rows=0 loops=1)
                -> Full-text index search on p using idx_post_search (title='ti')  (cost=1.05 rows=1) (actual time=0.0045..0.0045 rows=0 loops=1)
        -> Single-row index lookup on m using PRIMARY (id=p.member_id)  (cost=1.2 rows=1) (never executed)
-> Select #2 (subquery in projection; dependent)
    -> Aggregate: count(c.id)  (cost=2.45 rows=1) (never executed)
        -> Covering index lookup on c using FKs1slvnkuemjsq2kj4h3vhx7i1 (post_id=p.id)  (cost=1.35 rows=11) (never executed)


A couple of suggestions: if you can modify the db, add a dynamic view that implements the select statement, and map it as a read-only entity, and use the view to make performance tests directly on DBMS. Implement the where clauses with Specification, so than you can manage progammatically if the title field must match the keyword or not, if not given. Remove the order by and let the order be managed by the pageable parameter instead (you risk to order the results two times). Apart from this, which is the DBMS you are using? Can you post also the query that is performed by JPA?

The performance without the keyword parameter is not different. I checked the speed and it was the same.
I uploaded the query performed by JPA

do have an index on p.Id? do you mean it is slow on page 0 or a higher page? Plus what's your page size?

Yes with board_id and post_id together. The page size is 10 and It is slow no matter which page I search

@geon run the queries in sql mgmt studio with an EXPLAIN and check the execution plan. Your index is wrong and I'd bet you're missing some too.

18 seconds is only for the first query (select) or for the whole repository call (select + count)?

@SledgeHammer I uploaded the explain analyze result

@FrancescoPoli The whole repository call. It took 30 seconds in postman

@geon how long does it take for the query to run in sql mgmt studio? The times listed on your explain are fast.

@geon I suspect the query is fast, but the COUNT query is slow. Either way, limit/offset does not scale well (well documented). You'll see in mgmt studio that as you increase the offset, it gets slower and slower. If you use an offset of 5M, it'll probably take MINUTES. If my theory is correct, the only work around is to use cursor pagination instead which doesn't use count like limit/offset does, but it is more complex to use and implement. But it scales constant vs linear like limit offset does.

@SledgeHammer it took 30~ 40 seconds. Okay. I'll switch to Cursor pagination. Thank you so much.
